# ViewPager и PagerTabStrip текст заголовка в 2 строки

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Хочу заголовок страниц в ViewPager сделать в 2 строки, да ещё чтоб оформление строк отличалось. Подскажите как это сделать? По картинке поймёте, чего я хочу сделать. Всем спасибо за ранее за ответы!

[image: Картинка]

Comment: Привет от модераторов, мы прицепили вопрос к вашей новой учетной записи, теперь если что, вы сможете его редактировать (кнопка [edit]).

Answer (score 1):

Используйте лучше tablayout и сделайте кастомную view для табов с двумя полями

Comment: Можно, пожалуйста, пример tablayout?
Что за такая кастомная вью?
(Я автор темы, зарегистрировался)

Comment: В библиотеке поддержки дизайна.